# Convert Firebase Nested Map to List<Object>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following data in Firebase:

[image]

In Flutter, I have the following two objects:

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to convert the nested map of sets in Firebase to the List in Flutter but am having issues. What is the best way to convert a Map object with Map fields into a List in Flutter?

I've tried mapping the sets via this method and two different techniques:
[image]

[image]

I know I'm having an issue handling the map object and I've received different errors depending on my approach but usually it is similar to one of the following:

Error 1:
"type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List'"

Error 2:
"type '(dynamic) => ExerciseSet' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'"

Thank you for any help!

Comment: On Stack Overflow,please do not show pictures of code and text.  Copy the code into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: That makes total sense... Will do in the future!

Comment: I suggest doing it today in order to better serve the folks who might help you.  You can edit the question using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

If you have List of objects inside one object then you need to parse the list separately as the following

```dart
sets = (json['sets'] as List)
           .map((data) => ExerciseSet.fromJson(data))
           .toList();
```

Here `json` is decoded JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe after spending so many hours and finally deciding to post... I fixed it right after. Here's my working code:

[image]

Thank you for the quick response @Sanjay! I'll give yours a try to see if that works as well.

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't post pictures of code instead, post the code itself as suggested by @Doug